# Rails is confusing params after adding locale to the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, routes, internationalization, locale

I tried to internationalize my standing rails 4 page. I follwed [this](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/i18n_mehrsprachige_rails_applikation.html#i18n_url_path_prefix) basic but old guidelines and most of the steps worked well. The only big problem I encoutered is that rails is confusing my parameters on some pages.

Here is a small example:

```
#url: http://localhost:3000/en/list

<% @houses.each do |h| %>
  <%= link_to house_path(h) do %>
<% end %>
```

This worked as intended before but now rails is not able to assign everything correctly in the params so I will get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"houses", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :locale=>#<House id: 2, name: "zgerge">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Obviously rails is confusing the locale and the house instance so I was able to fix it by being more specific:

```
<% @houses.each do |h| %>
  <%= link_to house_path(:id => h) do %>
<% end %>
```

There are also some parts in my page where I am not sure how to fix it. One example for this would be forms:

```
#url: http://localhost:3000/en/h/1

<%= simple_form_for [@house,@booking] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Will return this error message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"bookings", :format=>nil, :house_id=>nil, :id=>"1", :locale=>#<House id: 1, name: "new house">} missing required keys: [:house_id]
```

Now what I am looking for is a solution that is a little more RESTful then changing the queries on every sinle occurance of the error.

I will provide additional parts of my code below. If something is missing that you would need to provide help I will gladly add that so just tell me!

```
#routes

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|de/ do

    mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'

    root :to => 'pages#home'

    get '/impressum', :to => 'pages#impressum', :as => 'impressum'
    get '/notes', :to => 'pages#notes', :as => 'notes'

    # shortened url for most visited pages
    get '/h/:id', :to => 'houses#show', :as => 'house'
    put '/h/:id', :to => 'houses#update'
    patch '/h/:id', :to => 'houses#update'
    delete '/h/:id', :to => 'houses#destroy'

    resources :houses, :except => [:show, :update, :destroy] do
        resources :pictures
        resources :bookings
    end

    put '/houses', :to => 'houses#activate'
    put '/houses/:house_id/pictures', :to => 'pictures#set_default'
    put '/houses/:house_id/bookings', :to => 'bookings#change_accepted'

    get '/list', :to => 'houses#f_index', :as => 'houses_list'

    devise_for :admins
  end
end

#application-controller
before_action :set_locale

private

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:locale]= I18n.locale
end
```

EDIT1:
[This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103042/starting-rails-i18n-and-url-helpers-seem-to-confuse-locale-with-id?rq=1) might have the same problem's cause. It got solved but I dont see how I could transfer this to my problem!